# Are there some strategies to automatically generate assessment questions and answers?

Tags: assessment, artificial-intelligence

To quote from [Artificial Intelligence in Education](https://curriculumredesign.org/wp-content/uploads/AIED-Book-Excerpt-CCR.pdf) by Charles Fadel etc.,

> Assessments define the education we get.

How can I automate the assessment design task using AI? Could anyone please provide some approved strategies?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there existed a decent AI (or nearly fully automated of any form) tool that does 50% of the educators' job, which is coming up with good assessment strategies

Comment: I imagine that such a tool would be, at best, about as useful as github copilot.  Which is to say that it might get your imaginative juices flowing as you design assignments, and might even be able to fill in small portions accurately for you, but it would basically never be able to get high quality assignments out on its own.

Comment: Just for fun, I tried out this tool: https://app.inferkit.com/demo.  I used the input `"This lab is to be completed in Java.  Consider the following problem:"` and it followed up with `"Check if a Double is positive or negative (i.e., if it is a number)

Integer.Equals(Double.DoubleName, Double.DoubleName);

The double will be a Double if it contains an integer value, or not."`  Not bad for approximating the spirit of some lab text, but obviously nonsense as an actual assignment.

Comment: @BenI. "positive or negative (i.e., if it is a number)" Right, who cares about zero.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout 